# Switching Image Stack with appendChild/replaceChild Function by Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild, removechild

Hi everyone I wanna switch sets of imagestacks by onclick function. Problem here is that the appendchild will always add a new imagestack rather than replacing the original one.

I have tried replacechild(), but obviously the global variables and functions cannot be affected by the local ones. Is there a better approach to achieving the switch function?

Added a simple demo below,

```js
// how to use the funciton on line 94
// for questions email felix@demont.is

var images10 = [
"https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"

];

var imagesbone = [
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"
];

var imageslung = [
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"
];

function ImageStack(options) {

  var self = this;

  self.img_array = options.images;

  self.stack = document.createElement('div');
  self.stack.style.overflow = 'auto';
  self.stack.style.maxWidth = '100%';
  self.stack.style.height = options.height;
  self.stack.style.width = options.width;
  self.stack.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
  self.stack.style.position = 'relative';

  var typeRegex = /(\D+)/
  var sizeType = options.height.match(typeRegex)[0]

  var numberRegex = /(\d+)/
  self.height_number = Number(options.height.match(numberRegex)[0])

  self.wrapper = document.createElement('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < self.img_array.length; i++) {

    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = self.img_array[i];

    image.style.display = 'none';
    image.style.position = 'absolute';
    image.style.width = options.width;
    image.style.height = options.height;
    image.style.top = 0;
    image.style.left = 0;
    image.dataset.iid = i;

    self.wrapper.appendChild(image);

  }

  self.image_elements = self.wrapper.querySelectorAll('img');

  self.scrollobject = document.createElement('div');
  self.scrollobject.style.width = '100%';
  self.scrollobject.style.position = 'absolute';
  self.scrollobject.style.zIndex = '2';
  self.img_count = (self.img_array.length > 15) ? self.img_array.length : 15;
  self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_count * self.height_number);

  self.scrollobject.style.height = self.scrollobject_height + sizeType;

  self.scrollUpdate = function(e) {

    self.height_number = self.stack.getBoundingClientRect().height
    self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_count * self.height_number);

    var sT = self.stack.scrollTop
    var hn05 = self.img_array.length - 1
    var hh = (self.scrollobject_height - self.height_number) / hn05
    scrollval = Math.floor(sT / (hh))

    self.currentimg = self.image_elements[scrollval].src

    self.stack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + self.currentimg + ')';

  }

  self.stack.addEventListener('scroll', self.scrollUpdate);

  self.currentimg = self.image_elements[0].src
  self.stack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + self.currentimg + ')';



  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var stackRect = self.stack.getBoundingClientRect()

    console.log(stackRect)

    self.height_number = stackRect.height
    self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_array.length * self.height_number);

    self.stack.style.width = stackRect.width + 'px'
    self.stack.style.eight = stackRect.width + 'px'
  })



  self.stack.appendChild(self.wrapper);
  self.stack.appendChild(self.scrollobject);

  return self.stack;

}

/*problems here*/
/*global var*/
var images = images10;

/*local var*/
function softtissue(){
 var images= images10;
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack);
}

function bone(){
var images= imagesbone;
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack); 
}
function lung(){
var images= imageslung;
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack);

}


/*how to switch the local var in global function*/
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack);
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="softtissue" type="button" onclick="softtissue();return false" class="button">
  Soft Tissue</button>
  <button id="bone" type="button" onclick="bone(); return false;" class="button">
 Bone</button>
  <button id="lung" type="button" onclick="lung(); return false" class="button">
 Lung</button>
</div>

<div class="example">
</div>
```

Comment: What I thought up, until now, was changing the position property from "relative" to "absolute",  overlapping image stacks, obviously a silly move.

Comment: @SaschaM78 This one is pretty similar to my last question, in which you suggest adding an "onload" to recall the getelementid function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your image arrays as a map instead of individual variables and change your buttons to call `setImageStack('bone')`, `setImageStack('lung')`, etc.

In the `setImageStack` function, create the `ImageStack` for that id if it doesn't already exist, store it for future reference, and insert it into the document.

See working example below.

```
const stacks = {
   bone: [
      // list of bone images
   ],
   softTissue: [
      // list of bone images
   ],
   lung: [
      // list of lung images
   ]
};


<button onClick="setImageStack('bone')">bone</button>
<button onClick="setImageStack('softTissue')">soft tissue</button>
<button onClick="setImageStack('lung')">lung</button>
```

```js
// a map to keep track of the ImageStack instances
const imageStacks = {};

const imagesByStackName = {
  softTissue: [
    "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
    "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
    // others omitted for this example
  ],

  bone: [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG",
    "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
    // others omitted
  ],

  lung: [
    "http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
    "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
  ]
};


function ImageStack(options) {

  var self = this;

  self.img_array = options.images;

  self.stack = document.createElement('div');
  self.stack.style.overflow = 'auto';
  self.stack.style.maxWidth = '100%';
  self.stack.style.height = options.height;
  self.stack.style.width = options.width;
  self.stack.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
  self.stack.style.position = 'relative';

  var typeRegex = /(\D+)/
  var sizeType = options.height.match(typeRegex)[0]

  var numberRegex = /(\d+)/
  self.height_number = Number(options.height.match(numberRegex)[0])

  self.wrapper = document.createElement('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < self.img_array.length; i++) {

    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = self.img_array[i];

    image.style.display = 'none';
    image.style.position = 'absolute';
    image.style.width = options.width;
    image.style.height = options.height;
    image.style.top = 0;
    image.style.left = 0;
    image.dataset.iid = i;

    self.wrapper.appendChild(image);

  }

  self.image_elements = self.wrapper.querySelectorAll('img');

  self.scrollobject = document.createElement('div');
  self.scrollobject.style.width = '100%';
  self.scrollobject.style.position = 'absolute';
  self.scrollobject.style.zIndex = '2';
  self.img_count = (self.img_array.length > 15) ? self.img_array.length : 15;
  self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_count * self.height_number);

  self.scrollobject.style.height = self.scrollobject_height + sizeType;

  self.scrollUpdate = function(e) {

    self.height_number = self.stack.getBoundingClientRect().height
    self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_count * self.height_number);

    var sT = self.stack.scrollTop
    var hn05 = self.img_array.length - 1
    var hh = (self.scrollobject_height - self.height_number) / hn05
    scrollval = Math.floor(sT / (hh))

    self.currentimg = self.image_elements[scrollval].src

    self.stack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + self.currentimg + ')';

  }

  self.stack.addEventListener('scroll', self.scrollUpdate);

  self.currentimg = self.image_elements[0].src
  self.stack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + self.currentimg + ')';



  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var stackRect = self.stack.getBoundingClientRect()

    console.log(stackRect)

    self.height_number = stackRect.height
    self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_array.length * self.height_number);

    self.stack.style.width = stackRect.width + 'px'
    self.stack.style.eight = stackRect.width + 'px'
  })



  self.stack.appendChild(self.wrapper);
  self.stack.appendChild(self.scrollobject);

}

// keep track of instantiated ImageStacks
const stacks = {};

// creates a stack for the specified image list and stores it in the cache map
function createStack(whichImages) {
  const images = imagesByStackName[whichImages];
  stacks[whichImages] = new ImageStack({
    images,
    width: '512px',
    height: '512px'
  });
  return stacks[whichImages];
}

// button onclick handler
function setImageStack(whichImages) {
  // get the ImageStack instance for this set from our map cache; create it if it's not already there.
  const stack = stacks[whichImages] || createStack(whichImages);

  const container = document.querySelector('.example');
  const child = container.firstElementChild;

  if (child) {
    container.replaceChild(stack.stack, child);
  } else {
    container.appendChild(stack.stack);
  }
}

// set up initial stack display
setImageStack(Object.keys(imagesByStackName)[0]);
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="setImageStack('softTissue')" class="button">
      Soft Tissue</button>
  <button onclick="setImageStack('bone')" class="button">
     Bone</button>
  <button onclick="setImageStack('lung')" class="button">
     Lung</button>
</div>

<div class="example">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried another approach which is deleting the previous appendchild() by removechild(), before adding a new one

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, I will be saving the answer acceptance quota for the best one, pretty sure that it's not me

Comment: Sorry it took so long. SO's snippet editor is really slow and clunky for me tonight.

Comment: Appreciate it, it's much better than mine

Comment: I updated it to do the initial display. Previously you had to click a button before you saw anything.

Comment: You could also instantiate all the image stacks up front if you wanted to for some reason (maybe to pre-load the images, for example) via something like `Object.keys(imagesByStackName).map(name => createImageStack(name))`

Comment: Yea, the lag of displaying scrolling images is really annoying. I'm trying to change the image into 64 bits coded directly in JS file, or as png; also I'm going to add a real time magnifier on these images during scrolling, maybe I should construct a loop in scrolling function, with onload()

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding a remove loop which clears all codes, before adding a new imagestack.

```js
var images= images10;
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack);


function softtissue(){
 let element = document.querySelector(".example");
while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
 var images= images10;
var stack1 = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack1);
}

function bone(){
 let element = document.querySelector(".example");
while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
var images= imagesbone;
var stack2 = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack2); 
}
function lung(){
 let element = document.querySelector(".example");
while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
var images= imageslung;
var stack3 = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack3);

}
```